# Is there a performance difference if we use "global" or "require" in node module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, require

lets say, we have node `app.js`

```
let lib= require("./big_library.js");
...
// some logic here, using myLib //
...
global.myLib = lib;
let other= require("./other.js");
```

and in `other.js` module we have:

```
let lib= require("./big_library.js");
//or it's better :  lib = global.myLib;
```

so, my question is directly with the theoretical perfromance effects. Will using `global.myLib` make it's performance better (accessing the library), instead of additional `require` in each module?

Comment: Have you benchmarked or profiled your code to find out for yourself? Have you considered if the performance drawbacks (if any) may be worthwhile considering the tremendous maintainability advantages of modules? Also, you really should be using native ECMAScript modules now, which will give you different profile/benchmark results again.

Comment: @T.Todua See https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_modules_ecmascript_modules - it's when you use the `import { x } from 'y';` syntax instead of using `require()`.

Answer (score 1):

The cost of second require is the cost of looking up its internal cache to see that the module is already resolved.

But I don't think it's only about the performance. It's about the order. require is guaranteed to be executed once, when you first call it. And no matter where you first call it.

On the other hand, if you start to rely on your explicit ordering (setting the variable always preceedes its usage), sooner or later you'll be hit by this.